# Find textBox, checkBox, any object by name C#

Tags: c#, object, arm, windows-ce

This is really weird, but I can't seem to find a specific textBox(i) or checkBox(i) in .NET CF. In .NET 3.5 I can create this function:

```
void checking(int input)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)this.Controls["checkBox" + input.toString()];
    if(checkbox.isChecked)
      //do something here
}
```

In this example, it gets the name of the checkBox (i.e checkBox1, checkBox2, etc).

However in .NET CF 3.5 for WINCE6, it keeps on telling me that I need an index inside Controls[] because it can't convert string to int. Does anyone know how to find the specific object without using that foreach statement? That foreach is useful but not for this because it loops through all the checkBoxes. Since I'm developing in ARM based, speed is everything. I'm using VS2008 C# to develop a desktop and mobile app.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

The following will cycle through 10 PictureBoxs used as rating stars changing them from gray to blue in my case.  The PictureBoxs are named in the following convention, pbStarX.  Where X is a number 1-10.  Ex: pbStar1, pbStar2, pbStar3, etc...

*Note: Using c#.Net VS 2010*

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("pbStar" + x, true)[0];
    pb.Image = MyProject.Properties.Resources.star_blue;
}
```

Alternative maybe when using c#.Net Compact Framework

```
private Control FindControl(Control parent, string ctlName)
{
    foreach(Control ctl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if(ctl.Name.Equals(ctlName))
        {
            return ctl;
        }

        FindControl(ctl, ctlName);                     
    }
    return null;
}
```

Use the above function like this...

```
Control ctl = FindControl(this, "btn3");
if (ctl != null)
{
    ctl.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but Find doesn't exists in .NET CF. I know how to use it in .NET, but it looks like .NET CF for some reason removed this option.

Comment: Does the added above alternative method (foreach) not work at all for you?

Comment: To be honest, that project was abandoned a long time ago. However, it would be nice to know the answer though. I'm moving towards android/cocoa...so .NETCF is somewhat dead for me.

Comment: nice feature, but one fault on the code:
`FindControl(ctl, ctlName)`; shoud be:
`var returnedControl = FindControl(ctl, ctlName);       if (returnedControl != null)                 {                    return returnedControl;                }`

Answer (score 1):

You are using un integer indexer and should pass un integer to it in order to retrieve object.
Try something like this:

```
void checking(int input) 
{ 
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)this.FindControl("checkBox" + input.toString()); 
    if(checkbox.isChecked) 
      //do something here 
}
```

This way you will find control by id

Comment: This is not a web app, and I don't think [`System.Windows.Forms.Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) has a method named `FindControl`.

Comment: Groo is correct. There is no FindControl.

Comment: As of right now, I'm using a PITA hack to get what I need. Pretty much I used:
<br/>
int index = this.Controls.Indexof(checkbox1);
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)this.Controls[index-input];
<br/>
Since checkbox1 has an index of 20, checkbox2 is 19, checkbox3 is 18...etc. This method works as long as I correctly index the darn thing. If I accidently go to an index that wasn't of type CheckBox, then exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Its should work, but alternatively you can use

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)this.Controls.Find("checkBox" + input.toString())[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Asif. However, it tells me that System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection does not contain definition for 'Find'.

Answer (score 1):

It's working my friends :) Please try this way

```
bool chkValue;
string chkName="checkbox1";
CheckBox myCheckBox = this.Controls.Find(chkName, true).First() as CheckBox;
chkValue = myCheckBox.Checked;
```