# Concatenate variable in variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a list of variable in ASP.NET (C#) that I'm trying to loop through without writing dozens of If statements. What I was hoping to do is just reference each of them with a variable and append it to the variable name. So something like the following:

```
string _id1 = Id1CheckBox.Checke.ToString();
string _id2 = Id2CheckBox.Checke.ToString();
string _id3 = Id3CheckBox.Checke.ToString();

int x = 1;

while (x < 20)
{
    if ("_id&" + x == "True")
    {
        _id + x = x.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        _id + x = 0;
    }
    x++;
}
```

The logic behind what I'm trying to do is I have several checkboxes on a form, Id1CheckBox, Id2CheckBox, Id3CheckBox, etc. I need get these values as strings so I can pass them as parameters in a SQL query. So basically If Id1CheckBox = true then _id1 = 1. If Id2CheckBox = true then _id2 = 2. If any are false then I would want something like If Id3CheckBox = false then _id3 = 0. Is this possible or will I just need to write several If statements instead of using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the checkboxes into an array like this:

```
private bool[] _checked;

public Form1() // Constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _checked = Controls
        .OfType<CheckBox>()
        .Where(cb => cb.Name.StartsWith("Id"))
        .OrderBy(cb => cb.Name)
        .Select(cb => cb.Checked)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Then loop the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _checked.Length; i++) {
    if (_checked[i]) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note: An array is a list of numbered variables (so to say). We say that the array is indexed. The index range goes from 0 to the length of the array - 1.

If you have 20 checkboxes add leading zeroes to the names up to number 9. E.g. `"Id05CheckBox"`. Otherwise the checkboxes won't be sorted right.

Note also that the form's `Controls` collection contains only the controls that are directly on the form. If the ckeckboxes are on a panel or tab-page or the like, then loop through the `Controls` collection of this container control: `panel1.Controls` or `page1.Controls` - you get it.

Comment: @Oliver I'm actually calling this all from a separate class so I'm not passing over the CheckBoxes as checkboxes to this other class, I'm only passing the value of true or false as a string to the class.

Comment: @doby48: I changed my answer accordingly. Storing the checkboxes in an array has the advantage that you can access them repeatedly and they will always show their current state, as the array only holds references to them. Therefore it might be a good idea to keep the checkbox array and to get the bool array from it when required like this: `bool[] checked = _checkBoxes.Select(cb => cb.Checked).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the loop and do something like this inside of your loop

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox )this.FindControl("_id" + x.toString()); 

if(checkbox.isChecked) 
  //do something here
```

Then you can just read the value from there.

Answer came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985584/find-textbox-checkbox-any-object-by-name-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a Dictionary and adding parameters in a foreach loop instead of attempting to combine variables. Heres the code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dictionary.Add("ID1", _id1);
dictionary.Add("ID2", _id2);
dictionary.Add("ID3", _id3);
dictionary.Add("ID4", _id4);

int i = 1;

foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
    if (pair.Value == "True")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, i.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, "0");
    }
    i++;
}
```